# LibreOffice not starting on Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: libreoffice

All of a sudden (or so it seems), the LibreOffice modules won't start. All I get is the LibreOffice community banner for a second and then nothing. It has been working just fine up until today and I have no idea what changed. The version is

```
LibreOffice 7.3.6.2 30(Build:2)
```

This is what happens if I run it from the command prompt:

```
$ libreoffice
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::deployment::DeploymentException'
Unspecified Application Error
```

Comment: Try to start from command line. Also try the solutions provided in this site for similar problems (questions).

Comment: Which version of LO are you using? In terminal type `libreoffice --version` and [edit] your question with the result.

Comment: This https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1647952#p1647952 appears to be a similar error: perhaps make sure you have libreoffic-gtk3 (or libreoffice-kf5) package installed?

Comment: Nope... installed both of those, still no different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an extension installed for the user locally, while the same extension was installed in the system in the meantime. Try removing the LibreOffice profile folders at `~/.libreoffice` and `~/.config/libreoffice`.

Comment: Aha... there we go... I removed those and reinstalled it all and now it looks like I am back in business... Super thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have libraoffice-gtk3 installed as this is a dependency and does throw those error messages.

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3
```

Let us know if you have sorted it out.

Comment: Yes, libreoffice-gtk3 is installed, but still the same error message.

Comment: Installed Open Office instead, but would still really like to find a solution for LO, since it appears to me as though OO is much slower when opening a document.